# Blackjack game in C

Tags: c

I was playing around with a very rudimentary blackjack kind of game, wherein the player draws random numbers ranging from 0 to 13 until they either choose to withdraw or their total exceeds 21. When they do withdraw, their total is compared to another random number ranging from 0 to 21, and based on the comparison, they win or lose.

Now, the problem I'm facing is that the game seems to run two iterations of the while loop, every time I input the value of B. Run the code and see for yourself. For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out the problem in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int sum=0,A[5],i=1,temp,pivot=0;
    char B='y';
    srand(time(NULL));
    pivot=rand()%21;
    printf("You are now playing vingt-et-un.\nTo draw a number, press y.To terminate at any time, press n.\n");

    do
    {  
        temp=rand()%13;
        sum=sum+temp;
        printf("The number you drew is %d, sum is %d.\n",temp,sum);
        if(sum>21) {printf("Busted."); break;} 
        scanf("%c",&B);
    } while(B!='n');

    if (sum<21&&sum>pivot)
      printf("You win. Pivot was %d",pivot);

    if (sum==21)
      printf("JACKPOT");

    if(sum<pivot)
      printf("Busted. Pivot was %d",pivot);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: When you hit enter a newline character is typed. So you are actually sending 2 characters to stdin.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&B);` --> `scanf(" %c",&B);` note the space I added, this cleans off whitespace such as `newline`.

Comment: this could be a seem like a silly suggestion, but I had the same problem and this worked for me... try two things... in the last line of i.e. `scanf()` `do{}`... replace `"%c"` with 1. `" %c"` or 2. `"% c"`... I hope either one works

Comment: Wow. I did not know a single space in the code could be 'game-breaking'. Thanks a lot! That fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in your OP from @Weather Vane and @vicky96. You need to add the preceding space in the [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Notes) statement, like so: `" %c"`. This will consume the newline character for you.

One clue as to solving this is actually already in your code! The two `getchar()` calls at the end are serving this very purpose: once the program finishes, wait for the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, you required two getchars so the '\n' newline char would also be consumed.

One suggestion to make this code more clear (intent/purpose) would be to replace the two `getchar()` calls with a single `printf("\n")` statement, and your command line will begin on a clean newline again.